# отрисовка двумерного массива js

Tags: javascript

Есть двумерный массив, точнее функция, которая его создаёт:

```
function createMatrix(width, height) {
    var matrix = [];
    var coll = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        matrix[i] = coll;
        for (var j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.className = 'cell';
            matrix[i][j] = div;
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

И есть  `div.field`, как вывести на экран сетку размерностью `width` на `height` состоящую из `div.field` заполненного элементами массива (в данном случае это div - вы).
Например:

```
var f =  createMatrix(20, 20);
```

ожидается получение сетки с размерами 20 строк, на 20 столбцов с ячейками заполненными дивами.

Comment: и в чем заключается вопрос? функция кстати не правильно работает :)

Comment: Всё равно приведённая функция работает неверно.

Comment: А ничего, что ваша функция тиражирует массив coll несколько раз в массив matrix? Фактически у Вас получается бессмысленная структура, т.к.каждое измерение matrix содержит один и тот же элемент. Ах да, самое главное то забыл - что вы подразумеваете под "отрисовать массив"?

Comment: @ Alex Krass, ну как бы так и задумано..... массив matrix наполнятся массивами coll, которые в свою очередь наполнены дивами

Comment: так вопрос то какой, если русскими словами если описать?

Comment: @pepel_xD, не `массивами coll`, а одним единственным массивом `coll`. Я правильно понял, что вы хотите получить таблицу на выходе из этого массива?

Comment: @ Grundy, вопрос заключается в добавлении массива в DOM.

Comment: @ Alex Krass, ну да, с доступом к ячейкам.

Comment: не ставь пробел между `@` и ником иначе оповещение не приходит.

Comment: стоит добавить пример разметки которая ожидается, или нужно просто слить все дивы в один?

Comment: @Grundy, по идее должна получиться сетка из дивов размерностью `width` на `height`

Comment: ну так добавь в вопрос разметку, которую ты ожидаешь увидеть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во первых, ваша функция работать не будет по одной простой причине - вы не создаете нового в массиве `matrix` и соответственно, в каждой ячейке будет один и тот же массив `coll`, то есть `matrix[0] == matrix[1] == matrix[3]`. А в массиве `coll` элементы, которые Вы можете вставить только один раз на страницу. Даже если вы пройдетесь циклом по высоте matrix, вы будете утыкаться в тот же `div`, который уже есть на странице.

Поэтому Вам надо переделать функцию, а вставка в DOM это стандартная операция, о которой можно прочитать в учебнике или туториале, ничего особенного.

```js
function createMatrix(width, height) {
    var matrix = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        matrix[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.className = 'cell';
            matrix[i][j] = div;
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}

document.getElementById("b").onclick = function(){
    var w = parseInt(document.getElementById("w").value);
    var h = parseInt(document.getElementById("h").value);
    var m = createMatrix(w,h);
    
    var d = document.getElementsByClassName("field")[0];
    for(var i=0; i<m.length; i++){
        var row = m[i]
        for(var j=0; j<row.length; j++){
            d.appendChild(row[j]);
        }
        d.appendChild(document.createElement('div')); //для разделения строк
    }
}
```

```css
.cell{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
Введите ширину: <input id="w" type="text"> <br>
Введите высоту: <input id="h" type="text"> <br>
<button id="b">отрисовать</button> <br>
<div class="field">
    
</div>
```